# MySQL searching by LIKE and AND

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have such SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM fl_entities WHERE  name LIKE '%FTSE%' AND source != 'ABC';
```

and didn't get results. But when i used

```
 SELECT * FROM fl_entities WHERE  name LIKE '%FTSE%' AND source is NULL;
```

I got the result

```
+----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
| id | name     | core_name | type   | source |
+----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
| 31 | FTSE     | FTSE      | factor | NULL   |
+----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

What is wrong with first query? Please help.

Comment: How can `name LIKE '%FTSE 100%'` get you the above result.

Comment: Find new solution    SELECT * FROM fl_entities WHERE  name LIKE '%FTSE%' AND NOT(source <=> 'ticker');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULLS are not equal to anything so you can't compare them by = or != comparisons you have to use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing a column to some value (even with a negation) then `null` values are always excluded. If you want them in your results you need to specify that explicitely, like

```
SELECT * FROM fl_entities WHERE  name LIKE '%FTSE%' 
AND (source != 'ABC' OR source is null)
```

A little demo can be found [here](http://rextester.com/AMK21901).

Comment: Find new solution.  SELECT * FROM fl_entities WHERE  name LIKE '%FTSE 100%' AND NOT(source <=> 'ticker');